# Why isn't database version control considered as important as application version control?

Tags: sql-server-2005, version-control, mercurial, kiln

I've recently started using Kiln Source Control for all my projects VB.NET code, and I don't know how I managed without it!

I've been looking for a database source control, for all my stored procedures, UDFs etc. However, I've found that there is not as much available for database version control as there is for my web files.

Why is database version control not considered as important as my web files? Surely all the programming in my database is just as important as the code in my code-behind and .aspx files?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't considered as important? It was certainly important for all projects I've been working on.

Comment: Kiln (and other VCs) can easily store your database assets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version controlling database objects IS important!

However, maybe it isn't considered as important because some people see a database merely as a tool that assists them? And external tools (normally) aren't version controlled.

One thing I've found hard to manage is the release process. Right now we're using red gates source control connected to svn. When it's time for release we do the same as with the rest of the code: Merge from one branch to the other. Then to deploy it we use sql compare to create a diff script between the merged revision and the actual database. Aside from some minor quirks and beginners mistakes I think this works well in a environment where there is no downtime (purposefully ;)) and which has a high speed development process (lots of releases).

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain your database artifacts in your version control system for same. 
Version control system is for versioning of artifacts and Artifacts can be Program code or database. We used same VC for code and database.

Answer (score 1):

VCS are designed to store versions of text. They can store binaries but it is less efficient. And the DB state itself is not a text and can't even be directly stored as a binary. You can store the SQL code though.

one solution is to store a full DB dump (SQL or binary), another - to store sequences of SQL scripts that change one DB state to the next one. The second approach can be automated in some environments and is there called migrations. if you want a separate specific VCS for a DB, you can think that migration tools are such VCS.

There are also tools that can compare two DB states and produce a diff that is able to change the first state to the second.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on whether you manage the database changes (like schema changes, migrations as mentioned by wRAR) as part of source code repository, in the form of sql scripts or other formats through the use of other tools, or do you consider this as database administration, and do that using traditional methods of backup/restore.

In my experience so far, although I wouldn't consider database management as any less important, it does happen on a very low frequency as compared to actual code changes. Your case is clearly different, but a combination of script files and database tools should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reality.

Database version control -- that is to say DDL, DML, and even data for necessary reference data required for an application to have basic functionality - is as important as all other application assets under version control.  **Databases should never be under any special exception where it is considered acceptable for their assets (objects and necessary reference data) to not be under version control.  *Ever*.**

So why have they been?  Simple.  The toolchains to keep managing those assets simple haven't always been up to snuff (in the case of SQL Server, prior to Visual Studio 2008 it wasn't shipped with first-party tools from Microsoft), and the toolchains differ on a vendor-by-vendor basis.  When those toolchains are deficient, unless the organization steps up to cover that deficiency, that deficiency remains.  It's technical debt, and some organizations do not prioritize it due to either time or (sadly) skill, when the tools to make it easy don't exist or require integrating third-party tools into the development workflow.

The worst is trying to bring older projects under version control, since you have to bring everyone kicking and screaming with you all at once, in addition to selling that value to the business.  I won't disagree that there may be more pressing immediate needs of the business, but getting database assets under version control needs to be *somewhere* on that list, even if it's a lower priority.

There's no excuse.  I've fought more than enough project managers, data architects, and even CIOs/CTOs on this -- I've even made it a point to have detractors kicked off of every project I'm working on.  **It *needs* to be done, and if it's not there needs to be a timeline that the business will agree to in which it *will* be done.**  Those who argue against it need to be shot in the face, and survivors need to be shot again.